# Nginx proxy https to http - routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

This is how I configure my Nginx

```
upstream stage {
   server example.com;
}
server {
    server_name IP;
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header protocol Token;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
              
      proxy_pass https://stage; 
   }
}
```

I see this on error.log

```
2021/11/03 15:26:14 [error] 40782#40782: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL hands
haking to upstream, client: IP, server: IP, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://IP:80/", host: "IP:10784"
```

How can I proxy user's request from http to https?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Disabling TLS with the `proxy_ssl_verify off` directive will resolve the issue, although it, well, disables TLS -- something you should not be doing on a public network connecting the proxying party and the upstream.

Here is the changed configuration:

```
upstream stage {
    server example.com:443;
}
server {
    server_name IP;
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
              
        proxy_pass https://stage$request_uri; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer, even after making it clear what solves your problem exactly, because disabling TLS is neither an answer to your SSL handshake problem, nor is it ever desired outside your very narrow usage context where it may or may not have [apparently] "worked".